# How to make visible an Image button of a class from another class?

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I have two classes:

1. RateBottomSheet (this has its own layout)
2. CustomRateBar (is a custom item)

I want to manage the visibility of some items of RateBottomSheetLayout from the class CustomRateBar.
I've tryied to instance the class 1 in 2. But not resulted. Anyone have an idea? I was thinking in a listener. But what should be the parameter? the view? Anyone have some example?

**Class RateBottomSheet:**

```
´class RateBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){
fun events() {
    imgEmoji.visible()
    feeling.visible()
    title.gone()
    subtitle.gone()
    txtOpinion.visible()
    btnSubmit.visible()
}

private var fragmentView: View? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.score_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    doBounceAnimation(this.fragmentView)
    return fragmentView
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.SheetDialog)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    customRB.init(5, context!!)
}
```

}´

**Class CustomRatingBar:**

```
´class CustomRatingBar : LinearLayout {
var vChildrens: MutableList<View>? = null
var mContext = context
var size: Int? = null

constructor(
    context: Context?,
    onSelectedStar: IOnSelectedStar
) : super(context) {
    this.onSelectedStar = onSelectedStar
}

constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)

fun init(item: Int, context: Context) {
    this.size = item
    this.mContext = context
    populate()
}

fun populate() {
    vChildrens = ArrayList()
    val lp = LayoutParams(
        (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT),
        (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    )
    var vChildren: View

    for (item in 1..size!!) {
        vChildren = buildStars(item)
        vChildren.layoutParams = lp
        this.addView(vChildren)
        vChildrens!!.add(vChildren)
    }
    this.requestLayout()
}

fun buildStars(num: Int): View {
    val item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_ratingbar, null)
    item.tag = num

    var viewHolder = ViewHolder(view = item)

    val unSelectedColor = PorterDuffColorFilter(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.btn_specialities_background
        ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
    )
    viewHolder.starItem.colorFilter = unSelectedColor

    viewHolder.starItem.setOnClickListener {
        LogUtils().v("selectOn old", " ${selectOn}")
        for (u in 0 until vChildrens!!.size) {
            val vChildrenn: View = vChildrens!![u]

            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view = vChildrenn)

            LogUtils().v("item", " ${item.tag.toString().toInt()}")
            if (item.tag.toString().toInt() < selectOn || item.tag.toString().toInt() > selectOn && first ) {

                **here I want to call the class event of the another class**
            }


            if (vChildrenn.tag.toString().toInt() <= item.tag.toString().toInt()) {

                val selectedColor = PorterDuffColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.star_color
                    ), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
                )

                viewHolder.starItem.colorFilter = selectedColor

            } else {
                viewHolder.starItem.colorFilter = unSelectedColor

            }

    }
    return item
}

inner class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    var starItem = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.starItem) as ImageButton
}
```

}´

Comment: Please post some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I agree. We need to know how the CustomRateBar updates the items in the RateBottomSheet. can you explain more about the functionality? Does the visibility of the ImageButton change based on the rating?

Comment: yes you can use listener. use boolean as paramter and use same param while setting visibility.

Comment: Posted! Please help me with some code, what should I pass in the Listener as parameter?